# Getting the essential phone numbers (police/fire department/medical/etc.) given my current location

Tags: windows, android, ipad-app, travel

I am looking for a program for Android, Windows, iPadOS or web-based that can give me the essential phone numbers (police/fire department/medical/etc.) given my current location.

Requirement: the phone numbers must be callable with a non-local cell phone/SIM card (i.e., I prefer international phone numbers than some special local numbers). E.g., calling the French medical emergency service with a US SIM card.

What I have found:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emergency_telephone_numbers only gives local numbers.

Comment: The emergency operator can be from almost anywhere in the world [with a phone signal of course] on 112. You don't need a list of individual national or local numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/112_(emergency_telephone_number)

Comment: @Tetsujin Good find!  A quick scan of that Wikipedia page indicates it is a GSM standard.  Does it work with other technologies too?  I know the USA also CDMA (IS-95), and Globalstar uses CDMA2000 (IS-2000).  I'm not sure if other systems use technologies besides GSM as well.

Comment: Franck, I'm 99% sure I've seen an Android app for exactly this use.  I think it was even offered for free at one point.  Now all you need is the name of that app, and a link to it;  I'm quite sorry, but I just don't remember.  If I come across it again, I'll be sure to post the name and link for you.

Comment: tbh, it's not something I've ever really researched, or had to test. It's just one of those "numbers travellers ought to know". I've never been anywhere my phone didn't work with the SIM already in it. I'd imagine if the phone can see a network it should connect, even if it may need to be unlocked to connect. iPhones have a "press 5 times to call emergency" feature even if locked, but it doesn't say what number it will cal or over what network structure.

Comment: Hmm… maybe the iPhone either contains, or can look up a list depending on where you are. https://support.apple.com/HT208076 [I'm ignoring the special emergency contacts list for this, as it's out of scope]